# Android: Scheduling applications for continued execution

Tags: android, scheduled-tasks, alarmmanager, timertask, scheduledexecutorservice

I have gone through various discussion threads and tried multiple iterations to have my application scheduled to repeatedly run at fixed intervals. I have been successful too, but starting the thread to get understanding how things work.

I had tried the implementation with ScheduledExecutorService as well as TimerTask and both did not trigger my task at right intervals. But found success with AlarmManager.

Please lead me in right direction to understand why the timing did not work well with ScheduledExecutorService and TimerTask.

The app is required to perform a task on a regular interval. Say, my task takes around 5 minutes to complete, I would like to keep it scheduled so that it runs once in every 30 minutes. When I built the application with ScheduledExecutorService or TimerTask, I found that it does not trigger the task at 30 minutes, but it triggered at 1 hour or even more. So far, with Alarm Manager, it seems to be working fine getting triggered at around 30 minutes(slight variation is still found, but better than the other two).

Comment: Please explain, completely and precisely, what "did not work well" means.

Comment: @CommonsWare Have updated the question with details. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I built the application with ScheduledExecutorService or TimerTask, I found that it does not trigger the task at 30 minutes, but it triggered at 1 hour or even more.

More importantly, it will not trigger at all once your process is terminated, which can happen at any point and, from the user's standpoint, *should* happen quickly, to free up RAM for other apps.

Your trigger delays are probably due to the device falling asleep. Your solution would not only tie up the user's RAM, but also would require you to prevent the device from falling asleep, which is horrible for battery life.

`AlarmManager` is a far more appropriate solution, as it does not require you to keep a service running or otherwise have a process around. Just be sure to use `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` as the way you respond to your `_WAKEUP` event, as the device will want to fall back asleep.

Comment: That's awesome. Your response helped me get what exactly I want and even understand more on the Android system. Am fresh on Android and every technical term encourages me to explore more. :)